# Could you explain this?

Tags: python

Quick question: in Python 3, if I have the following code

```
def file2dict(filename):
   dictionary = {}
   data = open(filename, 'r')
   for line in data:
      [ key, value ] = line.split(',')
      dictionary[key] = value
   data.close()
   return dictionary
```

It means that file MUST contain exactly 2 strings(or numbers, or whatever) on every line in the file because of this line:
`[ key, value ] = line.split(',')`
So, if in my file I have something like this

> John,45,65
>
> Jack,56,442

The function throws an exception.
The question: why key, value are in square brackets? Why, for example,

```
adr, port = s.accept()
```

does not use square brackets?
And how to modify this code if I want to attach 2 values to every key in a dictionary? Thank you.

Comment: Alternatively, limit `split` to a single comma: `key, value = line.split(',', 1)`. Oh, and: *"why key, value are in square brackets?"* I've no idea, there's no need for them to be.

Comment: `line.split(',')` is producing 3 values which you attempt to assign to 2 name. Using `John,45,65` as an example, do you want `key == "John"` and `value == "45"` (ignoring 65) or `key == "John"` and `value="45,65"` (ignoring the second comma when splitting), or `key == "John"`, `value=(45, 65)` (value being set to the tuple, or maybe list, containing the remaining items from the split)?

Comment: You can put key, value in square brackets or parentheses. Either way is fine for some reason, though since it's called tuple unpacking, and can be done without parentheses or brackets. Overall it's best to just leave brackets out of the picture.

Answer (score 1):

The `[` and `]` around `key, value` aren't getting you anything.

The error that you're getting, `ValueError: too many values to unpack` is because you are splitting text like `John,45,65` by the commas. Do `"John,45,65".split(',')` in a shell. You get

```
>>> "John,45,65".split(',')
['John', '45', '65']
```

Your code is trying to assign 3 values, `"John"`, `45`, and `65`, to two variables, `key` and `value`, thus the error.

There are a few options:

1) [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) has an optional `maxsplit` parameter:

```
>>> "John,45,65".split(',', 1)
['John', '45,65']
```

if `"45,65"` is the value you want to set for that key in the dictionary.

2) Cut the extra value.

If the 65 isn't what you want, then you can do something either like

```
>>> name, age, unwanted = "John,45,65".split(',',)
>>> name, age, unwanted
('John', '45', '65')
>>> dictionary[name] = age
>>> dictionary
{'John': '45'}
```

and just not use the `unwanted` variable, or split into a list and don't use the last element:

```
>>> data = "John,45,65".split(',')
>>> dictionary[data[0]] = data[1]
>>> dictionary
{'John': '45'}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use three variable's instead of two, make first one key,

```
def file2dict(filename):
   dictionary = {}
   data = open(filename, 'r')
   for line in data:
       key, value1,value2  = line.split(',')
      dictionary[key] = [int(value1), int(value2)]
   data.close()
   return dictionary
```

Answer (score 0):

When doing a line split to a dictionary, consider limiting the number of splits by specifying maxsplit, and checking to make sure that the line contains a comma:

```
def file2dict(filename):
    data = open(filename, 'r')
    dictionary = dict(item.split(",",1) for item in data if "," in item)
    data.close()
    return dictionary
```